# Run Bash Script for 6 Hours using Sleep

Tags: bash, sleep

How do you use the sleep function to run the bash script every minute for say 6 hours?

Thanks

Comment: You don't.  Stick a `* 3-8 * * * /path/to/your/script` in your crontab to run every minute from 3am to 8:59am, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to setup a cron job?

```
min hour     day month weekday command
*/1 10-15    *   *     *       /path/to/your/script
```

10-16 is an example of a six hour block where it would run. 10 being 10AM and 15 being 3PM

Comment: One thing i realized a second ago: `10-16` will run the script once a minute from 10:00 to 16:59 (almost 5pm).  That's 7 hours.

Comment: Oops. My apologies for bad basic math.